# New to SML / NJ. Adding numbers from a list of lists

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

> Define a function which computes the sum of all the integers in a
>   given  list of lists of integers. No 'if-then-else' or any auxiliary
>   function.

I'm new to to functional programming and am having trouble with the correct syntax with SML. To begin the problem I tried to create a function using pattern matching that just adds the first two elements of the list. After I got this working, I was going to use recursion to add the rest of the elements. Though, I can't even seem to get this simple function to compile.

```
fun listAdd [_,[]] = 0
|   listAnd [[],_] = 0
|   listAnd [[x::xs],[y::ys]] = x + y;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fun listAdd [] = 0
  | listAdd ([]::L) = listAdd L
  | listAdd ((x::xs)::L) = x + listAdd (xs::L)
```

should do what it looks like you want.

Also, it looks like part of the problem with your function is that you give the function different names (listAdd and listAnd) in different clauses.

Comment: How would I call this function? I tried listAdd ([4,5],[3,5]); and got type errors

Comment: That's because ([4,5],[3,5]) is a pair of lists, not a list of lists, like you said. Try calling it on [[4,5],[3,5]]. If you want the sum of a pair of lists, not a list of lists, then you'll need a different function. If that is the case, I can update the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, I'd say you probably want this :

```
fun listAdd : (int * int) list -> int list
```

Now, I would simply define this as an abstraction of the unzip function :

```
fun listAdd ls :
    case ls of 
        [] => 0
      | (x,y) :: ls' => (x + y) + (listAdd ls')
```

I think there is no point in taking two separate lists. Simply take a list that has a product of ints. If you have to build this, you can call the zip function :

```
fun zip xs ys :
    case xs, ys of
        [], [] => []
      | xs, _ => []
      | _, ys => []
      | x::xs', y::ys' => (x,y) :: (zip xs' ys')
```

In general, if you really wanted, you can write a far more abstract function that is of the *general* type :

```
fun absProdList : ((`a * `b) -> `c) -> (`a * `b) list -> `c list
```

This function is simply :

```
fun absProdList f ls =
    case l of 
        [] => []
      | (x,y) :: ls' => (f (x,y)) :: (absProdList f ls')
```

This function is a supertype of the `addList` function you mentioned. Simply define an anonymous function to recreate your `addList` as :

```
fun addList' ls =
    absProdList (fn (x,y) => x + y) ls
```

As you can see, defining the generic type-functions makes specific calls to functions that are type-substitutions to the general one far easier and much more elegant with the appropriate combination of : Currying, Higher-Order Functions and Anonymous Functions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want an `int list list` as input, but simply an `int list * int list` (pair of int lists). Besides this, your function seems to returns numbers rather than a list of numbers. For this you would use recursion.

```
fun listAdd (x::xs, y::ys) = (x + y) :: listAdd (xs, ys)
  | listAdd ([], _) = []
  | listAdd (_, []) = [] (* The last two cases can be merged *)
```

You probably want to read a book on functional programming fron the first page and on. Pick for example [Notes on Programming in SML/NJ](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/literature.html) by Riccardo Pucella if you want a free one.